# Non-existence of unbiased estimators for normal distibution

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X = (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ be a random sample from the normal distribution with mean $\theta \in \cal{R}$ (real numbers) and variance 1. Whether the estimand $g(\theta) = |\theta|$ has an unbiased estimator ?

From the instinct, I think it does not have an unbiased estimator, can anyone help?